# Encrypted message with Fs, 5s, and 6s

Tags: cipher

I've been redirected here from Cryptography SE.

This is a university assignment. We are supposed to be employees in a corporate environment that has managed to steal an encrypted message from another company of the field. Now, of course, are asked to decipher the ciphertext. The algorithm is unknown. We should get an English plaintext.

The ciphertext consists of a long sequence of Fs, 5s and 6s. I have noticed stuff such as:

- the only "double" sequence is 55. There's no FF or 66.
- F is always followed by a 5; you cannot find F6 in the ciphertext.

As a hint, we were told that "other than the algorithm, we should also find the alphabet".

I thought of some solutions, but e.g. I don't think that simple substitution can lead in any reasonable result.

For more context, the ciphertext is here:

```
5656F55656F556F5F55656565656F556F5F556F5F556F55656F556F55656F556F556F5F556F5F556F556F5F55656F556F55656F556F5F55656565656565656F5F5F55656F5565656F5565656F5F556F55656F556F556F5F556F5F556F5F5F5F5F5F5F556F55656565656565656F5F556F556F5F5F5F5F556F5F55656F556565656565656F5565656565656565656F5565656F55656F556565656F556565656F5F556F55656F5F55656F5F5F5F55656F556F5565656F5F55656F556F5F5F5F5F55656F55656F5F5F556F5F5565656F5F5F55656F5F5F556F55656F556F556F5F556F5F556F5F5F5F5F5F5565656F556F5F55656F55656F5F556F5565656565656565656F556F5F5F5F55656F556565656F55656565656565656F5565656F5F55656F5F556F55656F5F556F5F556F556F5F5565656F556565656565656F556F556F556565656F5F5565656F5F55656F5F5F5F55656565656F556F556F5
```

Please do not solve the exercise for me, I only want hints.

Comment: Preliminarily, it looks like two bits, F5, and 56, decodes to the below, haven't found more yet,  010110101001001000000010111111110010100000100110111111101111111110111011011110111100101100110000110101110011010000011011000100111000110001011010100100100000011011010011111010010010110101101010010010100110101101001111111100011011101110111010011011001011111111101000011011110111111110111001100101100100101001110111111101010111100111001100001111101010

Comment: if we convert to binary like @Sconibulus did, there are 398 characters, which can only be divided in group of 2 or 199

Comment: @Fabich I got 348, with the most likely groupings being 4 or 6 (prime factors 2,2,3,29) The next few things I've tried haven't worked out though.

Comment: F5 looks like a seperator. For reference, lengths of 56s after F5s: `1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 8, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 7, 9, 3, 2, 4, 4, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 3, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 5, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0, 8, 0, 0, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 9, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 8, 3, 0, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 3, 7, 1, 1, 4, 0, 3, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 5, 1, 1, 0`

Comment: I don't think PSE should be doing your university assignments. The purpose of the assignment is presumably for you to learn something, and you won't learn it by getting the denizens of PSE to do it for you...

Comment: Could it be Morse without spaces? I never did have the patience for Morse.

Comment: @HughMeyers: That's a super idea! The message begins with 0101 101 0100 1001 0 000, which could be `-.-. .-. -.-- .--. - ---` or "crypto".

Comment: (But it falls flat after that. And good luck with decrypting such a long message. The first word could very well be "kinky" or any of a lot of other words.)

Comment: If this is a university assignment then I assume that it must be something related to your course - what course is it? What are you studying exactly? I assume the context is quite important to solving it...

Comment: 348 is divisible by six. Braille is six bit. Is there a standard Braille to binary transformation? Alternately, there are these: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Six-bit_character_code. If something in here was covered in class, that might be it.